# Is there an applicationsserver like glassfish for visual basic?

Tags: vb6

Is there an equivalent application server like glassfish or tomcat for java for visual basic programs? Especially for visual basic 6 programs?

Comment: IIS along with COM+ (MTS & DTS) once served this purpose, but support for VB6 has been whittled away over time in favor of .Net languages.  You can still use these together but it often means a lot of "turning things back on" and other config headaches in recent versions of IIS.

Comment: I second that comment - and VB6 components were always a second-class citizen in the COM+ server, with C++ components being the real grown-ups. Having spent several years working on a system which was heavy on the VB6 COM+ components, I'm very glad to say I don't have to do that anymore.